# Switch cases in a google sheets script failing to recognize certain cases when typed into cell, but work when copy+pasted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, switch-statement

This is a very simple script and I have noted the cases that are failing.
The cases I tested the most was 'ts' when I type it into the cell, the value is not replaced, but when I copy from the script and paste it into the cell it does replace the value.
I have retyped that line of code multiple times to make sure that there is not an extra space within the quotes.
Any insight into why this is happening is much appreciated.

````
  switch (e.value) {
    case 'n':
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet5!B1');
      break;
    case 't':
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet5!B2');
      break;
    case 'i': //fails
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet5!B3');
      break;
    case 'c':
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet5!B4');
      break;
    case 's': //fails
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet5!B5');
      break;
    case 'st':
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet5!B6');
      break;
    case 'si': //fails
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet5!B7');
      break;
    case 'sc':
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet5!B8');
      break;
    case 'ts': //fails
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet5!B6');
      break;
    case 'is': //fails
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet5!B7');
      break;
    case 'cs':
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet5!B8');
      break;
    case 'd': //fails
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet5!B9');
      break;
    default:
      return;
  }
    return;
}```
````

Comment: Doing more testing, if the cell has anything other than one of the images or 'ts' in it before I edit it to 'ts' it works. (oh and for context, each of those Sheet5 cells has an image function in it)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your situation from your question. Can I ask you about the detail flow for replicating your issue?

Comment: Any error in view>Stackdriver logs?

Comment: Tried looking at them but it doesn't seem like they are recording any information about the trigger events other than the fact that they are happening. It also isn't reporting any errors with the script. Just tested a few times, on of the ones that did not succeed still says it running for 3 seconds instead of complete, but none of the others have that. After refreshing, that same log says completed in 0.7 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This works if you create and installable onEdit trigger since your changing values you can't use a simple trigger.

```
function onYourEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='Sheet10')return;

  switch (e.value) {
    case 'n':
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet11!B1');
      break;
    case 't':
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet11!B2');
      break;
    case 'i': //fails
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet11!B3');
      break;
    case 'c':
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet11!B4');
      break;
    case 's': //fails
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet11!B5');
      break;
    case 'st':
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet11!B6');
      break;
    case 'si': //fails
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet11!B7');
      break;
    case 'sc':
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet11!B8');
      break;
    case 'ts': //fails
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet11!B6');
      break;
    case 'is': //fails
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet11!B7');
      break;
    case 'cs':
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet11!B8');
      break;
    case 'd': //fails
      e.range.setValue('=Sheet11!B9');
      break;
    default:
      return;
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: I have already created an installable onEdit trigger for this (it only worked like 4 times before I realized I had to go that route). In your test was it working every time?